# Empty tooltip issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, tooltip

I have a simple WPF application with a button whose tooltip is binded to a TextBlock.Text:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Height="23" Margin="82,0,120,105" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1,Path=Text}" Click="button1_Click">Button</Button>
    <TextBlock Height="23" Margin="64,55,94,0" Name="textBlock1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="AD" />
</Grid>
```

In button1_Click, I have:

```
textBlock1.Text = null;
```

I expected no tooltip for the button after the button click. However, I am getting an emty tooltip. How do I fix this?

Comment: if you use a code-behind anyway can't you set the tooltip there directly? If not you might have to use a more complex template/construct  (WPF elements) for the ToolTip then a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set the `Text` to null, it will change to an empty string right away.

**Workaround #1:** a style that clears the value:

```
<!-- Do NOT set the ToolTip on the Button itself -->
<Style TargetType="Button" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Setter  Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ...}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ...}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Workaround #2:** Add a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to the binding which returns `null` if the `value` is `String.Empty`.

There might be other ways.

Comment: the question was how to fix - isn't this more like a comment?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: ...even though i think that just realizing what causes the problem is enough to lead most people towards solving the issue themselves. So my earlier version probably could have stood on its own.

Comment: this was just indendet as a hint - happend to me alot that I answered to point out some issues and allways got downvoted - now I don't like to downvote someone without comment - so I just rant ;) ... see now the answer is so good that I can give a upvote :D ... +1

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I would prefer a converter.